# Spring 3 <mvc:interceptors> flawed?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller, spring-3

I have a Spring 2.5.x application which I'm migrating to Spring 3 and just bumped into a little problem.

I have an handler mapping like so:

```
<bean id="handlerMappings1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="interceptor1" />
            <ref bean="interceptor2" />
            ....
            <ref bean="interceptorN" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="urlMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="/url1.html" value-ref="controller1" />
            <entry key="/url2.html" value-ref="controller2" />
            ....
            <entry key="/url100.html" value-ref="controller100" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and another one like this:

```
   <bean id="handlerMappings2" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="urlMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="/urlA.html" value-ref="controllerA" />
                <entry key="/urlB.html" value-ref="controllerB" />
                ....
                <entry key="/urlN.html" value-ref="controllerN" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I'm slowly replacing both with `@RequestMapping` annotations with a `<context:component-scan>` (which basically registers a [`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html)).

In Spring 3 I saw the [`<mvc:interceptors>`](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) tag which can be used to add interceptors to certain URLs but you can specify only one interceptor, at least that's what I see [from the schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd).

From what I can figure, I have to register one of these for each interceptor which will duplicate all my URLs for as many times as I have interceptors (and I don't even know in what order they will run).

On the other hand I can't add the iterceptors on the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` because they will run for all my controllers annotated with `@RequestMapping` and I don't want that.

So how can I specify interceptors is Spring 3 for some URLs, without repeating the URL's and 
 keeping the URL to controller mapping based on the `@RequestMapping` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at the `SelectedAnnotationHandlerMapping` and the `IgnoreSelectedAnnotationHandlerMapping` classes from the [springplugins](http://code.google.com/p/springplugins/downloads/list) project. The sources are some years old but the idea still stands.

There is a presentation on the creator's blog here: [Spring Framework Annotation-based Controller Interceptor Configuration](http://www.scottmurphy.info/spring_framework_annotation_based_controller_interceptors). Make sure you also read the comments to the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a custom interceptor which can delegate to a collection of injected interceptors.